# Is there attribute named "defaultSessionTimeOut" in tomcat server.xml?

Tags: tomcat6, web.xml, configure

when I want to set the "timeout" for my tomcat server,some one tell me do like that:

```
<Context path="/test" docBase="/test"     
　　defaultSessionTimeOut="3600" isWARExpanded="true"     
　　isWARValidated="false" isInvokerEnabled="true"     
　　isWorkDirPersistent="false"/>
```

but i can't find the "defaultSessionTimeOut" attribute in the official docs :http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/context.html . is the offical docs not complete ?

Answer (score 0):

Right idea. Just wrong config file, wrong attribute, and wrong time unit. It should be something like that:

```
 <session-config>
 <session-timeout>60</session-timeout>
 </session-config>
```

in the web.xml file. Note that session timeout is in minutes.